# What would cause a frontend to pull intermittently?

Tags: tires, truck, alignment

I just bought a new (to me) Sprinter van - 2006 Dodge Sprinter 2500 Van (140" wheelbase, high roof).  Generally speaking, it pulls to the right, but especially when going slowly, the wheel only pulls in short bursts.

**You can see what I'm talking about at 11 seconds (0:11) into this video (In the video, I'm idling in a parking lot): http://youtu.be/YAuXJc9fc4s**

What could be causing this?

Will a front end alignment fix this issue?

Thank you SO much! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may possibly have a bad tire or wheel, or a badly worn tie rod end or ball joint or suspension bushing, or a cracked suspension control arm, or a binding brake pad/shoe. Generally, alignment issues in the absence of worn or damaged parts will result in very consistent steering anomalies... with the exception of severe toe-in/toe-out issues, which may make one or both tires "bind-and-skip". Toe-in and toe-out issues, though, very seldom cause the vehicle to drift to either side - neither wheel gets steering preference. Instead, toe issues tend to make the vehicle wander side-to-side randomly as one tire "takes command", then the other tire "takes command".

First thing - check tire pressure on all four wheels, and get the same pressure (within very close tolerances) in all four. Run your flat-parking-lot test again and see if its character has changed at all. Second thing... jack up the right front wheel and spin it by hand - watch the tread pattern, watch the wheel rim. You're watching for any regular anomalies - bulge in the tire, sudden dodge to one side in the tread pattern, any imperfection in the wheel. If you don't find anything that jumps out at you, repeat that test at the right REAR wheel. Also, for both wheels, note whether you feel brakes binding as you spin the wheel. The brakes should give you just a little resistance to hand turning, but not very much.

Comment: The problem definitely ended up being bulges on both the front left and rear left tires.  Once those tires were removed from the setup, the vehicle still tracks right a bit, but not nearly as much.  Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think alignment could be the problem. But at that much you could see the difference even optical. The bursts comes because the wheels goes apart and then jumps back together or the other way. Could be also an oblique axis, but by doing alignment they will find this out.